# node from line 0:0 mismatched tree node: UNIT expecting UNIT

Tags: antlr, antlr3, tree-grammar

What does this error mean? Notice it expected a UNIT node and got what it was expecting...

```
Phase_2.g: node from line 0:0 mismatched tree node: UNIT expecting UNIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! I had forgotten the "tokenVocab" part on Phase_2.g.

```
options {
    (...)
    tokenVocab=Phase1;
}
```